# Talmud: Asking to sharpen the other?

Tags: talmud-gemara

We find in Shas that the Rabbi's asked questions although they knew their answers in order to sharpen the other:

Berachos 33b: And Rabba too knew this Mishnah - but merely asked Abbai this question because he wanted to hone Abaye's sharpness.

What does this mean - why would one get sharper by being asked a question?

Comment: As you quote it it seems pretty straightforward - he asked a question to hone someone's sharpness. Can you clarify precisely what it is you are looking for?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused about what you're asking, but isn't this just a metaphor of pedagogy? Even in modern English a smart person could be called "sharp"

Comment: See Nidah 14b (also Rabeinu Tam in tosafos shabbos 51a for that matter who slightly elaborates.